# Multilinestring to Linestring PostGIS 2.3

Tags: postgis, linestring

I am trying, as the title suggests, to transform a geometry that was a MultiLinestring into a Linestring. I first create a copy of the table I want to change, as a temporary table from which I can UPDATE the geom of the real one after altering the geometry. I then use this following query:

```
update cablage_pays_gex.cable set geom = NULL;
alter table cablage_pays_gex.cable alter column geom type geometry(Linestring, 2154);
update cablage_pays_gex.cable 
set geom = st_linemerge(cable_temp.geom) 
from cable_temp 
where cable_temp.id_cable = cable.id_cable;
```

But I get this error:

```
Geometry type (GeometryCollection) does not match column type (LineString)
```

What does it mean? What do I do wrong?

Comment: Are you sure cable_temp.geom is not a GeometryCollection?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per the [function documentation](https://postgis.net/docs/ST_LineMerge.html), ST_LineMerge will return a Linestring when each linestring in a MultiLinestring connects. If they do not, it'll return a MultiLinestring:

```
SELECT ST_AsText(ST_LineMerge(
    'MULTILINESTRING((0 0, 1 1), (1 1, 3 3))'::geometry));

> LINESTRING(0 0, 1 1, 3 3)

SELECT ST_AsText(ST_LineMerge(
    'MULTILINESTRING((0 0, 1 1), (2 2, 3 3))'::geometry));

> MULTILINESTRING((0 0, 1 1), (2 2, 3 3))
```

However, your error says the function is returning a GeometryCollection. As per the documentation, there are only two options when that occur:

> *Only use with MULTILINESTRING/LINESTRINGs. If you feed a polygon or geometry collection into this function, it will return an empty GEOMETRYCOLLECTION*

This means your table either has a Polygon or a GeometryCollection data point (or many of them). To find out, you can do:

```
SELECT DISTINCT ST_GeometryType(geom)
FROM cable_temp
```

Then you can find which data points have these geometries by doing:

```
SELECT * FROM cable_temp
WHERE ST_GeometryType(geom) IN ('ST_Polygon', 'St_GeometryCollection')
```

Afterwards, you can either fix these geometries or skip them in your processing.

**UPDATE**

Apparently, there are (at least) two other cases in which ST_LineMerge can also return a Geometry Collection, found by OP in the comments. These are if the geometry is **empty** or if it's **invalid**. I'll be condensing the information here for future reference.

The following mock-up query specifies the different possible returns for ST_LineMerge, as well as the original geometry and if it's valid and empty.

```
SELECT id, ST_GeometryType(ST_LineMerge(geom)) AS linemerge, 
    ST_AsText(geom) as geom, ST_IsEmpty(geom) as empty, ST_IsValid(geom) as valid
FROM mockup_table

id | linemerge             | geom                                     | empty | valid
---+-----------------------+------------------------------------------+-------+--------
1  | ST_LineString         | LINESTRING(0 0, 1 1))                    | f     | t
2  | ST_LineString         | MULTILINESTRING((0 0, 1 1), (1 1, 2 2))  | f     | t
3  | ST_MultiLineString    | MULTILINESTRING((0 0, 1 1), (1 1, 2 2))  | f     | t 
4  |                       |                                          |       | 
5  | ST_GeometryCollection | POLYGON((0 0, 1 0, 1 1, 0 0))            | f     | t 
6  | ST_GeometryCollection | GEOMETRYCOLLECTION(LINESTRING(0 0, 1 1)) | f     | t 
7  | ST_GeometryCollection | MULTILINESTRING EMPTY                    | t     | t 
8  | ST_GeometryCollection | MULTILINESTRING((0 0, 0 0))              | f     | f
```

**UPDATE 2**

Some points about the above table:

- Feature ID 1 represents Linestrings and Linestring-like geometries, such as CircularStrings.
- Feature ID 2 represents continuous MultiLinestrings and MultiLinestring-like objects, such as CompoundCurve and MultiCurve.
- Feature ID 3 represents discontinuous MultiLinestrings and MultiLinestring-like objects, such as CompoundCurve and MultiCurve.
- Feature ID 4 does not have a geometry (geom column is NULL), which is different from having an empty geometry (ID 7).
- Feature ID 5 represents non-Linestring-like geometries, such as Point, Polygon, MultiPoint, MultiPolygon, and CurvePolygon.
- Feature ID 6 represents GeometryCollections and GeometryCollection-like geometries, such as MultiSurface.
- Mesh-like geometries, such as PolyhedralSurface and TIN, as well as Triangle, are not acceptable inputs.

As a further testing, ST_LineMerge accepts Z and M coordinates, although they don't behave well. The Z ordinal is not checked when evaluating if the linestrings touch (so *MULTILINESTRINGZ((0 0 0, 1 1 1), (1 1 2, 2 2 2))* returns a merged Linestring, with the first Z value it finds). The M value is not considered and is dropped entirely.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. After running the first query I have only two results for the type existing in my table : Null (for objects without geometry) and ST_MultilineString. So no GeometryCollection there. Could it be the empty geometries ?

Comment: Hmm, weird. I checked here, ST_LineMerge with Null geometry only returns Null object. Try executing: SELECT id_cable, ST_GeometryType(ST_LineMerge(geom)), ST_GeometryType(geom) FROM cable_temp WHERE ST_GeometryType(ST_LineMerge(geom)) = 'ST_GeometryCollection'. This should give you a list of features that are returning problematically, together with id and original geom type. Are there particular features with this behaviour? or is your entire table returning a collection?

Comment: Indeed, I've got 8 features being returned. I'll check them to see, and give feedback when I do. I suspect more than 1 vertex on the same place...

Comment: And so, 4 of the features where positive to ST_IsEmpty(), and the 4 others where negative to ST_IsValid(). No more GeometryCollection. Thanks a lot :)

Comment: @GuiOmClair Great that you found the problematic geometries. I didn't even know that a Linestring could be invalid! Living and learning. Updated my answer to reflect your findings.